# C++ Thread Safety For Addition Operation

Tags: c++, multithreading, math, addition

Suppose you are updating a shared data structure from 2 different threads where the order of operation does not matter. So all that is required is a correct result from the operations from two threads.

The code below works fine on my system, but I don't think this is thread safe.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// A vector of [100] which all have 0 as their initial values.
std::vector<int> common(100, 0);

void add10(std::vector<int> &param){
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = param.begin();
        it != param.end(); ++it){
        *it += 10;
    }
}

void add100(std::vector<int> &param){
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = param.begin();
        it != param.end(); ++it){
        *it += 100;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Print vector
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = common.begin();
        it != common.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "==> Initial Vector" << std::endl;

    std::thread t1(add10, std::ref(common));
    std::thread t2(add100, std::ref(common));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    // Print vector again
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = common.begin();
        it != common.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "==> Resulting Vector" << std::endl;
}
```

What I'm concerned here is a data race that when;

- Say t1 is iterating through the 10th element. Gets the value from iterator as 0.
- And at the same time, t2 is iterating through the 10th element so both of them read in the value of 0.
- Then they do addition, 10 and 100 respectively.

So can there be a data race when assigning back to the vector?

**Edit:**

For STL data structures, turns out you can use it like `std::vector<std::atomic<int>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as those operations are not atomic. You use iterator to take a value, add something to it and stores the value back - there is quite some machine code behind this. Another thread can jump in and replace your value at any time.

You must ensure thread-safety of this code.

You can disassemble the binary or generate assembly code to see how this is performed at the machine level. In GCC you can use the `-S` (note: capital S) switch to generate assembly listings.

Comment: Is there a way to do this concurrently on a same data structure?

Comment: Assuming that you're not modifying vector contents (say, by pushing new stuff), you may use atomic integers. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Comment: IIRC the Qt library have an easy-to-understand atomic integer code. You may be interested in checking it out. It's used internally for reference counting, which by the way is a good place to look for a clever solutions of such thread-safety related problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is a data race if one threads writes an object which is accessed (read or written) by another thread without proper synchronization. If a program contains a data race its results are undefined. Your program contains no synchronization but it does access shared objects concurrently, i.e., it results in undefined behavior.

I found the article on [benign data races](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) quite interesting: even if it is acceptable not to get the correct results things can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is undoubtedly a data race, in fact after running your code twice I found some of the entries of the resulting vector were 10, rather than 110, as they are supposed to be. You can see this immediately by running your executable through helgrind, i.e. `valgrind --tool=helgrind ./race`, and it will tell you exactly what the problem is:

```
==3176== Possible data race during read of size 4 at 0x5C41040 by thread #3
==3176== Locks held: none
==3176==    at 0x4010CD: add100(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (race.cc:19)

==3176== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #2
==3176== Locks held: none
==3176==    at 0x40106C: add10(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (race.cc:12)
```

Use `std::atomic<int>`, rather than `int`s, dealing with the problem of `delete`'d atomic copy constructors as necessary.